# embedded sign using docusign without template id

Tags: docusignapi

I create one form and these form is store in database and generate one pdf i want to get sign in this PDF with embedded rest api, I can done this with templateID but i don't use template i want to use my own pdf to signature..

I use below code for using templateId

```
$data = array("accountId" => $accountId, 
    "emailSubject" => "DocuSign API - Embedded Signing Example",
    "templateId" => $templateId, 
    "templateRoles" => array(
        array( "roleName" => $templateRoleName, 
                "email" => $emailSender, 
                "name" => $recipientName, 
                "clientUserId" => $clientUserId
            )
        ),
    "status" => "sent");
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Have you read through the [DocuSign Developer Center](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center) yet?  There's a features section that covers embedded signing (and sending) which shows an example that does not use a template.

You'll want to create a request that looks like this:

```
{
    "status": "sent",
    "emailSubject": "Envelope with Embedded Signer",
    "documents": [{
        "documentId": "1",
        "name": "contract.pdf",
        "documentBase64": "base64 document bytes...",
    }],
    "recipients": {
        "signers": [{
            "email": "john@email.com",
            "name": "John Doe",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "clientUserId": "1234"
        }]
    }
}
```

See the [embedded signing](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/embedding-docusign#EmbeddedSigning) section.

Comment: {
  "errorCode": "UNSPECIFIED_ERROR",
  "message": "Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string."
}

Comment: Are you using actual base64 bytes in the "documentBase64" parameter?